# Prevent parent event fire on jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have very annoying problem in my code.

When I change a checkbox state, the click event of it parent fires as well.
I've tried different methods to solve this problem like:

1. `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`
2. `event.stopPropagation();`
3. `event.preventDefault();`
4. `return false`

Unfortunately no one works for be (probably it's not related to "event propagation" issue). How can I make `('.sortable').click` not to be fired on checkbox change?

**HTML**

```
<div class="sortable">
    <span>Hello all!</span><br />
    <label>Click on me<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></label>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('.sortable input[type=checkbox]').change(function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('checkbox changed');
    });

    $('.sortable').click(function(){
        alert('sortable clicked');
    });
});
```

You can find the code on: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kPLqJ/1/)

Comment: You are handling two different _types_ of events here – it is only natural that you can not “cancel” the _click_ event that bubbles up to the parent element, when you are only handling to the _change_ event on the checkbox.

Comment: The first event on the checkbox will need to be a `click` event too.

Answer (score 2):

As you have bind click event to parent div, it is firing that also. You can check the 'target element if not checkbox' condition in parent click event handle like below

```
$('.sortable').click(function(event){
        if(event.target.type!="checkbox")
        console.log('sortable clicked');
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rr4D6/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

coz You're Stopping propagation of `.change()` event and handling `.click()` event

Just Try changing:

```
$('.sortable input[type=checkbox]').change(function(event){ ... });
```

to:

```
$('.sortable input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event){ ... });
```

Hope it helps!

Here is a working example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vjKGv/

Comment: find himself?
The click event is fired on space at least for the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ6q3/24/)

```
$(function(){

    $('.sortable').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('sortable clicked');
    });
    $('.sortable input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event){
        //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.stopPropagation();
        //event.preventDefault();
        console.log('checkbox changed');
    });
});
```